# US criminal case - change of venue

Tags: united-states, trial, sixth-amendment

In the US, if a defendant in a criminal trial (in state court) wants to change the venue of the trial, is it possible to have it changed to another state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

There is some room for change of venue from, say, one county to another, or one municipality to another, *within the same state*. In certain circumstances this may even be constitutionally required. See *Sheppard v. Maxwell*, 384 U.S. 333, 363 (U.S. 1966) ("where there is a reasonable likelihood that prejudicial news prior to trial will prevent a fair trial, the judge should continue the case until the threat abates, or transfer it to another county not so permeated with publicity"). But, there's no mechanism to move a state criminal trial to another state.

A cousin of the scenario you're talking about is where D has committed crimes in multiple states. In such a situation the prosecutors from different states (and also the federal system) may meet and co-ordinate their strategies, and part of that will be deciding who charges what and who goes first. An example of this is the DC sniper case, which I remember pretty vividly because I grew up in the area. The Maryland and Virginia prosecutors reached an agreement to try them in Virginia first, and second in Maryland.

Comment: I believe you're remembering it wrong. VA tried them first, MD second. Maryland wanted their trials to go forward because of the concern the VA convictions would be overturned.

Comment: @pboss3010 Is that what happened? I thought Doug Gansler pushed hard to get the first crack at them?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.C._sniper_attacks): *Change of venue requests by defense attorneys were granted, and the first trials were held in the independent cities of Chesapeake and Virginia Beach in southeastern Virginia.*

Comment: Very interesting

Comment: Correct for state court, but not for federal court. For example, the Oklahoma City bombing trial was held in federal court in Denver, Colorado (which is a different state than the one in which the crime was committed).

Comment: @ohwilleke well yeah but the question asked about state court specifically.